# How to find workplaces with high proportion of young (20-something) college-educated population?

Tags: colleagues, company-culture, student

How does a 20-something find a white collar job with lots of 20-somethings? Statistics/finance/accounting/applied-math field.

Comment: Well it is ageist for a start

Comment: A lot of companies, when describing who they are, e.g. in an "about" section on their website, will simply state sth like "we are a young company ...", which just means that most employees there are on the younger side of things.

Comment: maybe OP could provide some clarification as to why this is what they are looking for. I have a hunch it's about finding a good peer / social circle (ie - built in friends) and if that is the case, it's not an unreasonable request and would be less ageist that if they said something like "because I only like young people"

Comment: @Underverse How does a 20 year old white male find a nice white collar job with lots of 20 year old white males?

Comment: @paulj He didn't mention sex OR race in the question, so quit race baiting.

Comment: @CrazyPaste Age is also a protected class. Quit treating age as a less protected class. Thank you.

Comment: @paulj I'm not treating age as a "less protected class".  I'm simply pointing out that you reworded the OPs question to make it sexist and racist... Shame on you.

Comment: I had no intentions of being celibate and thought i'd be more likely to get married if I worked ina younge nviron,ent

Comment: Why would you be more likely to get married if you work in a young environment?

Comment: @Erik Because a workplace with younger people has a deeper pool of candidates for marriage? While a greater number of people now meet online the workplace is still a likely place to find a life partner.

Comment: @Underverse that sounds like a pretty bad reason for picking a workplace, and also a great way to make things awkward with your colleagues..

Comment: It's not that he's looking to just go to work and find a wife.  He wants to work with people his own age so he can create a proper social circle.  He will know more people and the chances of him finding marriage material increases tenfold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply to them and see who interviews you. If they are on the younger side chances are the workplace will be predominantly younger people. If the interview is on-premises it should also help you get a feel for it.

Smaller, newer companies also tend to have younger employees in general compared to older companies or larger ones with people that have been working there for decades or hierarchy so bloated people with decades of experience need to handle parts of it.

Answer (score 3):

> How does a 20-something find a white collar job with lots of
>   20-somethings?

Many of the best jobs are found through your personal or professional network of friends. If you have friends who are in their 20s and working in white collar jobs, I'd start there.

Another option is to look at company websites in their careers section. If the language talks about the kinds of things 20 somethings would like it's a reasonable guess that they are trying to attract candidates like you. Also, if they show pictures of folks around your age, that's a good sign.

If you are recent graduate, you should consult your university's placement department. Often they have insight into companies hiring new graduates.

Finally, consider working through an agency. They have insight into which companies are hiring, and what kind of culture you could expect.